# Datawarehouse with FactInternetSale and FactFinance

Tags: ssas, data-warehouse, cube, olap-cube, sql-server-data-tools

I'm studying about DW. And I try to practice on AdventureWorkDW2012.

But I have this issue.

I created two cube:

1) Internet Sale cube: From FactInternetSales & DimDate with hierachy in DimDate( Fiscal Quarter -> Fiscal Year -> Date Key)

2) Finance Cube: From FactFinance and DimDate with hierachy in DimDate (with instance is DimDate1) same as Internet Sale cube.

**Data View for Internet Sale Cube:**

[image: Data View]

**Data View for Finance Cube:**

[image]

** Hierachy for DimDate.dim (same with DimDate 1.Dim)**

[image]

**Solution explorer:**

[image]

But the results are very different. As you saw on my Solution explorer:

1) In dimension has the exist of "Fact Internet Sale.Dim", not have any of FactFinance. Why?

2) The hierachy is created well for Internet Sales cubes, but not for Finance. I create pivot table form excel for Internet Sales cubes and get this hierachy, but not for FactFinance.What is the reason for that? Please help me to make hierachy with FactFinace

Thank a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for first question,in FactInternetSales have primary key. So It belong to dimension after I create the cube. I tested with FactCallCenter, it's ok.

But I still stuck in the second question. Who know how make hierarchies and make It work with FactFinance (non primary key) ?